# Error UWP with mvvmcross + xamarin forms

Tags: xamarin, mvvm, xamarin.forms, mvvmcross, xamarin.uwp

I,m trying to navigate to another view in a xamarin forms + mvvmcross with

```
public ICommand GoCommand
   {
       get
       {
           return new MvxCommand(() => ShowViewModel<SecondViewModel>());
       }
   }
```

Android works fine, but UWP crash ("Error HRESULT E_FAIL has been returned from a call to a COM component") in Show method:

```
public async void Show(MvxViewModelRequest request)
   {
       if (await this.TryShowPage(request))
       {
           return;
       }

       Mvx.Error("Skipping request for {0}", request.ViewModelType.Name);
   }
```

Any idea?? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Could you show more detail about `SecondViewModel` and `SecondPage` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Great!!, I've already seen my mistake. I needed to add this code

```
       var start = Mvx.Resolve<IMvxAppStart>();
       start.Start();
```

Method result:

```
   public MainPage()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();

        var start = Mvx.Resolve<IMvxAppStart>();

        start.Start();

        MvxFormsWindowsUniversalViewPresenter presenter = Mvx.Resolve<IMvxViewPresenter>() as MvxFormsWindowsUniversalViewPresenter;

        if (presenter == null) 
        {
            return;
        }

        this.LoadApplication(presenter.XamarinFormsApp);
    }
```